# Script para pegar tags com classe especifica e acionar onload

Tags: javascript

Preciso de um código em JavaScript que busque todas as tags `img` com a classe `load` e insira nelas a função `onload="loader(this)"`.

A ideia nisso é que todas as imagens com a classe `load` recebam a função do `onload` que ira trocar o valor do `src` pelo valor do image.

Funcionaria como um plugin [lazy load](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload), mas sem APIs.

Se já existe algo do tipo aqui me indiquem o link pois não consegui encontrar algo do tipo.

Comment: Em javascript puro, ou usando alguma biblioteca, tal como o jQuery?

Comment: Mas o `onload` não vai executar somente quando a imagem já estiver carregada? Como isso pode ser um *lazy load*? (E se você estiver pensando em **remover** o `src`, então o `onload` nunca vai executar - pois o evento de "imagem carregada" não disparará enquanto ela não for carregada de fato...)

Comment: José, o jeito de marcar uma pergunta como "resolvida" é escolher uma resposta e marcá-la como correta. Ou então publique sua própria solução, citando as respostas que ajudaram, e marque essa como correta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creio que em vez de injectar javascript dentro do html seja melhor amarrar event handlers às imagens desejadas...

Se quer usar javascript puro pode usar assim, em duas versões +/- semelhantes:

```
var imagens = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
for (var i = 0; i < imagens.length; i++) {
    imagens[i].addEventListener('load', function (e) {
        loader(this)
    });
}
```

[**Exemplo online**](http://jsfiddle.net/rk4eD/)

**Ou, com outro estilo de escrita:**

```
function loader(event) {
    var estaImagem = event.target; // e usar "estaImagem" em vez de "this" como sugere
}
var imagens = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
for (var i = 0; i < imagens.length; i++) {
    imagens[i].addEventListener('load', loader)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Uma solução usando [Jquery](http://jquery.com/) seria:

```
$(function(){
    $('img.load').attr('onload','loader(this)');
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CqTp3/)